# Ubuntu 10.10 - startx not working

Tags: gnome

So I have an Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 on same hdd, different partitions.
If I choose to boot into linux when I-m in grub, everything works perfectly.
The problem is, if I'm trying to start the ubuntu from vmware player(from a physical partition) - gnome(startx) doesn't work.
Log here: http://pastebin.com/NrzMm0eN

Any advice?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: l-m? w-t? I-d-u.

Comment: huh? what's this?

Comment: any other ideas? :)